I made a discord clone and I am trying to send message but I get axios error internal server error 500

This is the chat component where I am making the API request using axios.post and this is where I get the error:
const formSchema = z.object({
    content: z.string().min(1),
})

export const ChatInput = ({
    apiUrl,
    query,
    name,
    type
}:ChatInputProps) =>{
    const {onOpen} = useModal();
    const router = useRouter();
    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            content: "",
        }
    });

    const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

    const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>)=>{
        try {
            const  url = qs.stringifyUrl({
             url: apiUrl,
             query,
            });

            await axios.post(url, values);
            form.reset();
            router.refresh();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, "chat input");
        }
    }
    return(
        <Form {...form}>
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <FormField 
                 control={form.control}
                 name='content'
                 render={({field})=>(
                    <FormItem>
                        <FormControl>
                            <div className='relative p-4 pb-6'>
                                <button type='button'
                                 onClick={()=> onOpen('messageFile',{apiUrl, query})}
                                 className='absolute top-7 left-8 h-[24px] w-[24px] bg-zinc-500 dark:bg-zinc-400 hover:bg-zinc-600 
                                 dark:hover:bg-zinc-300 transition rounded-full p-1 flex justify-center items-center'
                                >
                                    <Plus className='text-white dark:text-[#313338]' />

                                </button>
                                <Input disabled={isLoading} 
                                 className='px-14 py-6 bg-zinc-200/90 dark:bg-zinc-700/75 border-none
                                 border-0 focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-offset-0 text-zinc-600 dark:text-zinc-200'
                                 placeholder={`Message ${type === 'conversation' ? name : '#'+name}`} 
                                 {...field}
                                 />
                                 
                                 <div className='absolute top-7 right-8'>
                                    <EmojiPicker onChange={(emoji:string)=>field.onChange(`${field.value} ${emoji}`)} />
                                 </div>

                            </div>

                        </FormControl>
                    </FormItem>
                 )}
                 />

            </form>
        </Form>
    )
}

This is my API where I handle the POST request:
import { currentProfilePages } from "@/lib/current-profile-pages";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { NextApiResponseServerIo } from "@/types";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";


export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponseServerIo,
){
    if(req.method !== 'POST'){
        return res.status(405).json({error: "Method not allowed"})    
    };

    try {
        const profile = await currentProfilePages(req);
        console.log(profile, "jjjjjjjj");
        const {content, fileUrl} = req.body;
        const {serverId, channelId} = req.query;
  
        if (!profile) {
            return res.status(401).json({error: "Unauthorized"});
        }

        if (!serverId) {
            return res.status(400).json({error: "ServerId is missing"});
        }

        if (!channelId) {
            return res.status(400).json({error: "ChannelId is missing"});
        }
    
        if (!content) {
            return res.status(400).json({error: "Content is missing"});
        }

        const server = await db.server.findFirst({
            where: {
                id: serverId as string,
                members:{
                    some:{
                        profileId:profile.id,
                    }
                }
            },
            include: {
                members:true,
            }
        });

        if (!server) {
            return res.status(404).json({message:"server not found"});
        };

        const channel = await db.channel.findFirst({
            where: {
                id:channelId as string,
                serverId:server.id
            }
        });
  
        if (!channel) {
            return res.status(404).json({message:"Channel not found"});
        }
    
        const member = server.members.find((member)=>member.profileId === profile.id);

        if (!member) {
            return res.status(404).json({message:"Member not found"});
        }

        const message = await db.message.create({
            data: {
                content,
                fileUrl,
                channelId: channelId as string,
                memberId: member.id,
            },
            include: {
                member: {
                    include: {
                       profile:true
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        const channelKey = `chat:${channelId}:messages`;
        res?.socket?.server?.io?.emit(channelKey, message);

        console.log(res.json(message))

        return res.status(200).json(message);
    } catch (error) {
       console.log("[Message_Post_Error]", error);
       return res.status(500).json({message:"Internal Error message index"})
    }
}

Github Repository
I am trying to send message but I am getting axios error 500 Internal Server Error. I am unable to find the error

I would love to just reproduce this from the github, but your github has left out so much of the stuff needed that it would take longer to set up the project than to actually debug the issue.
You should share the server logs on what is exactly going wrong. From what I can tell there are only 5 lines that could produce the error, so it would be nice to know which one actually did.

i shared my server log please let me if this helps find the issue
